# How is my acceptance criteria (in suggested edits review) compared with the comunity?

Tags: support

When I have done several reviews in the suggested edits queue, is there anyway that I can see my stats compared with other people votes, or against the final result ?

Just to know if I am too hard or too soft ..

Comment: Each review shows what the other reviewers voted.  Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2430052

Comment: On another note, why people think they need to put "EDIT:" and "Edited for clarity" in their posts is beyond me.  Every post on every Stack Exchange site comes with a [detailed edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1041606/revisions).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I know. I was asking about some kind of global statistic, in the line of 'you rejected 5 edits, of which 3 where finally rejected (60%) and 2 finally aproved (40%). You approved 3 edits, of which ...'

Comment: There's a "more" link in that review window that you can click on... It will give you stats for all of the people who reviewed the suggested edit, including yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/254278/my-acceptance-criteria-in-suggested-edits-review?UserId=1926369) would show that for your SO account:

```
select case when mine.votetypeid = 2 
            then 'approve' 
            else 'reject' 
       end as [mine]
     , case when theirs.votetypeid = 2 
            then 'approve' 
            else 'reject' 
       end as [theirs]
     , case when se.approvaldate is not null then 'Approved'
            when se.rejectiondate is not null then 'Rejected'
            else 'still open' 
       end as [result]
     , count(*) as [cnt]
from suggestededitvotes mine
inner join suggestededitvotes theirs 
        on theirs.suggestededitid = mine.suggestededitid
inner join suggestededits se on se.id = mine.suggestededitid
where mine.userid = ##UserId##
and theirs.id <> mine.id
group by mine.votetypeid
       , theirs.votetypeid
       , case when se.approvaldate is not null then 'Approved'
            when se.rejectiondate is not null then 'Rejected'
            else 'still open' 
       end
```

For my own account the result was:

```
   mine |   theirs  |   result      |   cnt
------------------------------------------------------------        
approve |   reject  |   Approved    |   401
reject  |   reject  |   Approved    |   97
approve |   approve |   Approved    |   1814
reject  |   approve |   Rejected    |   238
approve |   reject  |   Rejected    |   159
approve |   approve |   Rejected    |   29
reject  |   approve |   Approved    |   570
reject  |   reject  |   Rejected    |   527
```